# JS - Motion Detect EventTrigger Constantly Triggering Function

Tags: javascript, html5-video

i'm working on a project in which i have a while() loop acting as an event listener. OnEvent i need to reset .currentTime in an html video.

the problem is, the event is triggered by a motion sensor, which whenever activated is supposed to set the video at a current playtime. Because the motion sensor is always listening and always alerting when it detects motion, my video is also stuck in this loop, constantly being reset when the event listener is triggered instead of playing its full section. i can't seem to figure out a way around this.

since my code is quite long at this point, i'm simply going to include the event-listener and trigger function.

appreciate any help!

```
       function processWV() {
           var startTime = +new Date(),
               changed = false,
               f;

           context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
           f = detectf();



           if (experimentType === MASK_EXPERIMENT) {
               drawMasks(f);
           } else {
               highlightf(f);


           }


            //console.log(+new Date() - startTime);

           setTimeout(processWV, 25);
       }



   function listening(f) {


       if (f == false) {
           section = 2;
           updateVideo();
           return false;
       } else {
           section = 1;
       }


       for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
           var f = f[i];
           context.fillRect(f.x, f.y, f.width, f.height);
       }

   }

   function updateVideo(){
                console.log('update');
               $("#video")[0].currentTime = 14;
   }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "continuously running loop"? Do you have  while(true) or something in place?

Comment: Also, ```var f = f[i];``` in your for loop will overwrite the original value of f. For statements in JavaScript do not create a new scope!

Comment: the values need to be overwritten. and yes to the first point. it's listening to a sensor.

Comment: Isn't the while loop blocking any rendering? I would expect this code to block the browser and not allow any animation to occur.

Comment: I would expect to solve this problem with setInterval and some callbacks, taking advantage of the runtime's existing event loop.

Comment: this is working code with the exception of the afformentioned problem-- rather than play section two of the video, it just repeats where the the currenttime marker has been set for section two. setinterval will kill the live feedback by adding a delay. thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Can put up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yeah, please put up a link to some code. We need to at least know what event is triggering `listening`.

Comment: there are too many dependencies for a JS fiddle. ultimately, this is a logic problem, i dont think it's a scope issue. the question boils down to how do i trigger a function once from a while() loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give the trigger function additional params to ensure that it exits the beginning of section 2.

if it's looping, it's probably just being called to to that same spot over and over again. what you should do is say something like:

```
if(section==2 && video.currentTime < whatever_section_1_end_time_is){
set to section 2;
}
```

hope that makes sense.